# Static Y Axis in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

When my chart renders on Highcharts, I want the y axis values to stay the same, even after I show/hide different series. I do not want to set a static min/max since the values range from graph to graph. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the **mix** and **max** range after the initial load inside the **chart.events.load** callback and do a yAxis update with those values.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5c6fxsam/

```
  chart: {
    events: {
        load() {
        let chart = this;

        chart.yAxis[0].update({
            min: chart.yAxis[0].min,
          max: chart.yAxis[0].max
        })
      }
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addSeries

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update

---

Or if you don't need to have those values calculated from the values on the initial load you can set them to some fixed values:

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.min